# Inverse of a floor function

Tags: calculus, functions, alternative-proof, ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function

I was working on beautiful inverse function problem ,I solved it like below but I am looking for new idea(s) to solve it .can any one help me ?
$f(x)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor \to f^{-1}(x)=?$
I listed my tries below as answers .It will be appreciated any help .

Comment: Have you got a typo in your post or does $f(x) = x + f(x)$?

Comment: What is the domain of $f\,$?

Comment: It was corrected .thank you both

Comment: @dxiv :Domain is  $\forall x \in R$

Comment: $f$ is not surjective on $\mathbb{R}$ so it has no inverse. Try to find an $x$ such that $f(x)=1.5$ for example.

Comment: @dxiv :NOte that $f(x)$ is $1-1$ function , you can trace it by a figure .

Comment: $f$ is injective, but not surjective. Whether it's invertible or not depends on how you define its codomain.

Comment: $f (x)=x+[x]=2 [x]+\{x\} $. So $f^{-1}(x)=[x]/2 +\{x\} $ if $[x] $ is even, the inverse does not exist otherwise.. Example. $f (13.7)=26.7$ and $f^{-1}(26.7)=26/3 +.7=13.7$.

Comment: Note if $[x] $ is odd then $f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't exist and isn't defined.

Comment: $f(x) $ most certainly is ***NOT*** 1-1.  The is no x so that f (x)=1.5.  It's injective but not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=f(x)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor \\\to \lfloor y\rfloor=\lfloor x+\lfloor x\rfloor \rfloor\\
\lfloor y\rfloor=2\lfloor x\rfloor \to \\
\lfloor x\rfloor=\frac12 \lfloor y\rfloor \to\\y=x+\frac12 \lfloor y\rfloor \\x=y-\frac12 \lfloor y\rfloor \to\\(x\leftrightarrow y)\\f^{-1}(x)=x-\frac12 \lfloor x\rfloor$$

Comment: $f\left(f^{-1}(1.5)\right)=f(1.5-0.5)=f(1)=2 \ne 1.5\,$. You need to restrict the domain of $f^{-1}$ more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=n_x+p_x ,y=n_y+p_y\\0\leq p<1\\
y=x+\lfloor x \rfloor \to n_y+p_y=n_x+p_x+n_x \\\to 
\begin{cases}n_x=\frac12 n_y\\p_x=p_y\end{cases}\\x=n_x+p_x=\frac12 n_y+p_y=\frac12 (\lfloor y\rfloor)+(y-\lfloor y\rfloor)\\x=y-\frac12 \lfloor y\rfloor \\
f^{-1}(x)=x-\frac12 \lfloor x\rfloor$$ 
and third try was

since $f(x)$ passes $(0,0)$ guess that $$f(x)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor \to f^{-1}(x)=ax+b\lfloor x\rfloor \\f(1.5)=2.5\\f(1)=2 \to (2,1),(2.5,1.5) \in f^{-1}\\
\begin{cases}2a+2b=1\\2.5a+2b=1.5\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}2a+2b=1\\2.5a+2b=1.5 & 0.5 a+2b-2b=1.5-1 \end{cases}\\a=1\\b=-0.5 \\\to \\f^{-1}(x)=ax+b\lfloor x\rfloor=1x+(-0.5)\lfloor x\rfloor$$

any more idea ?

thanks in advanced .